# What happens if you only work your arms at the gym?

Tags: bodybuilding

What happens if you only work your arms at the gym?

Comment: look at all the "never skip leg day" photos and you get the idea how it looks

Answer (score 5):

You will get stronger arms.

It's working out, not rocket science.

Comment: But like if you work out only your arms for like 10 years will you get only big well defined arms and be fluffy in the rest of the body?

Comment: Assuming your diet is well managed, and you are using the principles of progressive overload to develop strength rather than just maintain it, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You make no mention of your goal.  So, let's assume that it's one that's shared by many people: a **balanced**, **symmetrical**, and **aesthetic** physique.  Working only arms will not accomplish that since you are neglecting other body parts. In a sense, if you were an artist, you're painting a small portion of the picture and leaving the rest unfinished.  Additionally, while you may get bigger arms, and that's not a given, your potential for an overuse injury increases.  And, having an unbalanced physique may put more demands on the other body parts that you have neglected.  All in all, working only one body part is never a good idea.

Comment: Also: Arms are part of the rest of the body. Super strong arms that are connected to a weak back and core, by shoulders that aren't used to bearing weight, don't have a lot of practical value for actually using the arm strength that one has developed.